# Postsharp error - this aspect must be applied to a(n) method

Tags: postsharp

Recently, I upgraded to Windows 10, VS 2015 and installed the latest Postsharp as of today (4.2).  Prior to this, the solution was building correctly and everything was working fine.

Now, I'm getting an error:

```
Cannot apply the aspect XXXXXXXXX to XXXXXXXX: this aspect must be applied to a(n) method
```

The Postsharp DLL attached is 3.1.42.9.  I tried uninstalling Postsharp, and installing manually the 3.1.69 version and it worked fine.  Any ideas?  Do the DLLs and extension in visual studio need to be synchronized?

Comment: Could you also provide the code snipped for the aspect itself and the location where the aspect is applied? Your description of PostSharp versions used is also not clear. What is the version of NuGet package installed and what is the version of VS extension? These are loosely coupled and for optimal experience it's recommended that they match in major and minor version numbers.

Comment: Yes, I resolved this problem yesterday. It was due to mismatching versions of the DLL and VS extension.  However, the error message was extremely misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the project was using Postsharp Nuget DLL v3.1.xx.  I installed VS 2015, which has a much newer version of Postsharp extension (v4.1.xx).

I updated the project to the latest DLL version as well (v4.1.xx), and it worked.

The error message was extremely misleading though, and I only discovered this by chance as I tried to use VS 2013, and that had a different Postsharp extension version.  Also, the issue is that VS 2013 and VS 2015 now cannot live 'side-by-side' if you use PostSharp, because if you upgrade the project's DLL to the latest for VS 2015, then VS 2013 will not work.  In my case, it wasn't a problem as I wanted to use VS 2015, but good to know about it.

Comment: I'm glad the problem has been resolved for you. However, this is most probably resolved just by upgrading to the newer NuGet package which may contain a related bug fix (e.g. the upgrade from 3.1.42 to 3.1.69 or to 4.1.x). Please note that PostSharp 4.1 supports both VS 2015 and VS 2013, if you experience any issues with 'side-by-side' use then you can report them as bugs to PostSharp team.

Comment: Thanks @AlexD! I'll try it side-by-side as well and see about it.

Comment: Actually it works as well in VS 2013 now.  The issue is that from the 'Extensions and Updates', I couldn't update Postsharp to v4.xx.  However, downloading it for VS 2015 updated it for VS 2013 as well.